# list doubles when back pressed in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my `Fragment` in navigation view, it is opened as default when I clicked an item in navigation view and return back to this fragment the items in lists are doubled for example in list it has apple when i press back it shows two apples

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private  String category_id;
 // Movies json url
private  String url ;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList=new ArrayList<Movie>() ;
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

 public AllProductsActivity() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    category_id = bundle.getString("IDS");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_layout, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categories_list);

    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    category_id = bundle.getString("IDS");
    VerifyURL();
    return rootView;
}

private void VerifyURL() {

    if (category_id.equals("no_product")) {
        url = "http://192.168.43.149/Newfolder/gap.php";
        DownloadJSON();
    }else{
        url = "http://192.168.43.149/Newfolder/gap.php?category_id=" + category_id;
        DownloadJSON();

    }
}

private void DownloadJSON(){

    pDialog=new
            ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();



    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(obj.getString("price"));
                            movie.setYear(obj.getString("description"));



                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    } }}
```

This is my `Adapter` class where it opens a `Activity` i want to open a `Fragment` I already changed get `Fragment` manager to the get child `Fragment` manager but it does not work

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_products, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.PI1);
        ImageButton AddcarT=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_add_cart);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PN1);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PD1);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PD2);

        // getting movie data for the row
        final Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        // rating
        rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

        // genre
        genre.setText(m.getYear());

        // release year
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ProductsViewActivity.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("rank", m.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("flag", m.getThumbnailUrl());
                activity.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        AddcarT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(activity, m.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Pass all data rank

            }
        });

        return convertView;}


}
```

Comment: in your fragement onCreateView use condition like if(adapter== null){ then fetch data} else adapter.notifydatasetchanged

Comment: it shows cannot resolve method notifydatasetchanged

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: it will not show any data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not calling your api multiple times to use pagination, call `movieList.clear()` or `movieList = new ArrayList<>();` before adding data into it.

So your code will be:-

```
// Checking of movieList is not null
if(movieList != null) {
    movieList.clear();
} else {
    movieList = new ArrayList<>();
}                   
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
   try {
      JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
      Movie movie = new Movie();
      movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
      movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
      movie.setRating(obj.getString("price"));
      movie.setYear(obj.getString("description"));

      // adding movie to movies array
      movieList.add(movie);

   } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateView() method, clear your list.

```
movieList.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 if (adapter==null) {
            prod = new ArrayList<>();
            adapter = new ProductsAdapter(prod, getActivity());

            if (Constants.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())){

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(GlayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }else {

                Constants.showToast(getActivity(),"No Internet!!");
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(GlayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }else{

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(GlayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply clear the list before adding data into ArrayList. It means when you click on the back press it will clear first and then insert data into the list. So you always get an updated list.

```
list.clear()
```